# Has the conjecture of Guillemin-Sternberg been proven for relevant physics cases?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics, gauge

From a working physicist's perspective, the conjecture of Guillemin-Sternberg (and its generalisations) seems to state in a highly technical manner that quantization commutes with gauge-fixing.

In how far has this conjecture been generalised and proven to be of practical use to QFT and string theory? Does it for instance back up the claim that gauge-fixing the string action in light-cone gauge and then quantising it is equivalent to quantising it first, and then removing unphysical states (covariant quantisation)?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Guillemin-Sternberg+geometric+quantization+conjecture

Comment: Thanks. I know this resource and the references within but it is too technical for me to understand.

Comment: Guillemin-Sternberg for string theory is conjectured to hold if the quantization is done "right", whatever that means, but it's unlikely that it's written down rigorously anywhere in all details.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Qmechanic's comment: you can do it "wrong" in which case light-cone gauge quantization and covariant quantization (of the string) disagree. "Wrong" includes the case of non-critical dimension. See Green-Schwarz-Witten