# "Constrain then quantise" vs. "quantise then constrain"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, quantization

Consider a classical system whose configuration space is a manifold $M$, and which is subject to some constraint $\mathcal{C}=0$.

[E.g. the system could be a particle moving in $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\mathcal{C}=x_1$ constraining its first coordinate to be zero. Or the system could be a gauge theory, with $M$ the space of connections on a time-slice, and $\mathcal{C}=\nabla\cdot\vec{E}$ the Gauss constraint.]

Let $\mathcal{P}\subset T^\ast M$ be the "reduced phase space" of the system, i.e. the submanifold of $T^\ast M$ on which the constraint is satisfied.

It seems there are (at least) two ways to quantise such a system:

1. Dirac Quantisation ("quantise then constrain"). First define an unphysical Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}= L^2(M)$. Then define the physical Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{dirac}\subset \mathcal{H}$ as the kernel of the constraint operator $\hat{\mathcal{C}}:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$.
2. [Geometric Quantization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization) ("constrain then quantise"). First choose a polarisation of $\mathcal{P}$, i.e. a foliation of $\mathcal{P}$ by Lagrangian submanifolds. Then choose any leaf $\mathcal{Q}$ of this foliation.  Finally, define the physical Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{geom}=L^2(\mathcal{Q})$.

I'm interested in the relation between the physical Hilbert spaces obtained using the two methods. If the state of the physical system is represented by some element of $\mathcal{H}_{geom}$ in geometric quantisation, what is the element of $\mathcal{H}_{dirac}$ that represents it in Dirac quantisation? Both Hilbert spaces are meant to describe the same physical system, after all.

I'd be satisfied with a broad-strokes description of how these two quantisation procedures are related. I'm fine with some mathematical details being swept under the rug, e.g. problems that occur in infinite dimensions.

Comment: Dirac constrains Poisson brackets into [Dirac Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket) which he *subsequently* quantizes, canonically, no?

Comment: Yes, I also believe that the usual Dirac quantization is constrain then quantize. It is the Gupta-Bleuler, BRST etc. quantizations that have to deal with the non-physical states. (I.e. could be seen as quantize then constrain.)

Comment: Most likely Dirac invented both techniques, so the naming could be ambiguous. My naming follows Henneaux & Teitelboim, see chapters 13.2 and 13.3.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "quantization commutes with constraints" usually refers to [Guillemin-Sternberg conjecture](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Guillemin-Sternberg+geometric+quantization+conjecture). It has only been proved for a limited class of (gauge) theories.

It should stressed that the word "constraints" here refer to a (gauge) symmetry, cf. the [Dirac conjecture](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Dirac+conjecture). It does not refer to polarization in [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization) [quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization).

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490342/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: I'm sure this is the technically correct answer, but I think this goes far past the level of rigour I need. I really just want a broad-strokes recipe for how to go between Geometric Quantisation states and Dirac Quantisation states. Like, assuming all the mathematical objects play nicely -- there are no topological obstructions, whatever -- is there a plausibility argument for why the two Hilbert spaces are "getting at the same thing"?

Answer (score 2):

Take your first example of a particle in $\mathbb R^d$ constrained to lie on $x_1=0$. In Dirac Quantization the constraint on the wavefunctions is not $x_1 \psi(\vec x)=0$, but rather $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\psi(\vec x)=0.$$
This tells us that the 'physical states' in Dirac Quantization are constant in the $x_1$ direction. Therefore there is a simple map between physical states in Dirac Quantization and Geometric Quantization: $$\psi_{\text{dirac}}(x_1,...,x_d)=\psi_{\text{geometric}}(x_2,...,x_d).$$

To make the analogy with Gauge theories, the constraint $x_1=0$ is analogous to fixing the gauge: $\partial_i A^a_i=0$ (or whatever other gauge you like) and the constraint $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}=0$ is analogous to the Gauss constraint: $iD_i\frac{\partial}{\partial A^a_i}\equiv D_iE_i^a=0$ (recall $E_i^a\equiv i\frac{\partial}{\partial A^a_i}$ because it is canonically conjugate to $A^a_i$). (Also $D_i$ here is the covariant derivative.)

Comment: In that first example, how does Geometric Quantisation lead to the wave function $\psi(x_2,...,x_n)$? I must be missing a step in my current understanding, since the constraint surface $x_1=0$ has odd dimensions and tus can't admit a polarisation.

Comment: @nodumbquestions. The leaf $x_1=0$ is described by the coordinates $x_2,...,x_d$. Therefore functions on the leaf depend only on said coordinates.

Comment: what happened to the $p_1$ coordinate?

Comment: Wavefunctions are either only functions of the coordinates or the momenta, but not both (because you can't diagonalize both $\vec x$ and $\vec p$). Therefore you either have $\psi(x_2,...,x_d)$ or $\tilde\psi(p_2,...,p_d)$, which is just the Fourier transform.

Comment: After imposing the constraint you have a 2n-1 dimensional phase space (*not* 2n-2 dimensional). So I'm not sure how to choose a polarisation and get a hilbert space from that.

Comment: @nodumbquestions How can there be momenta in the $x_1$ direction if $x_1$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I agree that in the simple case we're discussing, it seems "obvious" that after setting $x_1=0$ we should also throw out the $p_1$ coordinate of phase space. But in the general case, I don't know what the prescription should be: what should we "throw out"?

Comment: You have to throw out the momentum conjugate to the constraint. Let the constraint be $C(\vec x)=0$. This is a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$. To set the momentum conjugate to the constraint to zero, we simply set the normal vector of the surface to zero. The normal vector is simply $\sum_i C_i \hat x_i$, where $C_i \equiv \frac{\partial C}{\partial x_i}$. The directions $\hat x_i$ have to simply be replaced with the momenta $p_i$, which gives the constraint $\sum_iC_ip_i=0$, which along with $C=0$ are the two constraints on phase space.

Comment: Okay. Does this still work for the general case where the constraint depends on positions and momenta $C(\vec{x},\vec{p})$?

Comment: @nodumbquestions No in that case I don't know how it works

Comment: Ok but $C(\vec{x})=0$, with no momentum dependence, is uninteresting. Then the configuration space is $Q=\{\vec{x}:C(\vec{x})=0\}$, the phase space is $T^\ast Q$, and we just quantise in the easy/usual way to get the Hilbert space $L^2(Q)$. Only when momenta are involved in the constraint do things get interesting.

Comment: @nodumbquestions I'm not sure if it's uninteresting: Gauge theory for example has the gauge fixing constraint which is expressed entirely in terms of the gauge field (and not the momenta), so it is a constraint of the type $C(\vec x)=0$.