# Constraints on Phase Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics

This question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746695/) motivated me to record to the following fact: Consider a $2n$ dimensional phase space with coordinates $q_1,...,q_n,p_1,...,p_n$. Consider the constraint $C(\vec q)=0$. What is the constraint on the momenta which, together with $C=0$, reduces the phase space dimension to $2n-2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one performs a change of coordinates: $\vec q\to \vec x(\vec q)$. These coordinates are to be chosen such that $x_1(\vec q)=0\longleftrightarrow C(\vec q)=0$.

Let $\vec \pi$ be the momenta conjugate to $\vec x$. They are related to the original coordinates and momenta by
$$
\pi_i=\frac{\partial q_j(\vec x(\vec q))}{\partial x_i} p_j. \tag{1}
$$
In the new coordinates it is clear that the constraint on the momenta is simply $\pi_1=0$. Using (1) we see that this is just
$$
\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_1}{p_i}=0.
$$
**This is the answer to the question**, but I will go on to elaborate on other aspects.

---

In the path integral one must insert delta functions in the integrals over $\vec q$ and $\vec p$. The appropriate combination of delta functions is
$$
\delta(x_1)\delta(\pi_1)=\delta(x_1)\delta\left(\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_1}{p_i}\right) \tag{2}
$$
Since $x_1(\vec q)=0\longleftrightarrow C(\vec q)=0$, (2) can be written
$$
\bigg{|}\frac{\partial C}{\partial x_1}\bigg{|}\delta(C)\delta\left(\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_1}{p_i}\right) \tag{3}
$$

---

In gauge theory, the 'original coordinates' are the gauge fields. The constraint is the gauge fixing condition $C^a=0$. So-called $x_1$ is simply the gauge transformation parameter $\xi^a(x)$. Therefore (3) for gauge theories is
$$
\bigg{|}\frac{\partial C^a}{\partial \xi^b}\bigg{|}\delta(C^a)\delta\left(\int dx\frac{ \partial A^b_i(x)}{\partial \xi^a}{\pi_i^b(x)}\right) \tag{4}
$$
Using $\frac{ \partial A^b_i(x)}{\partial \xi^a(y)}=\delta_{ab}D_i\delta(x-y)$,  (4) finally becomes
$$
\bigg{|}\frac{\partial C^a}{\partial \xi^b}\bigg{|}\delta(C^a)\delta\left(D_i\pi^a_i\right) 
$$
We recognise the first term as the Fadeev-Popov determinant; the second term as the gauge fixing constraint and the last term as the momentum constraint.

Answer (score 1):

OP is considering a Hamiltonian system with a single [primary constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) $C\approx 0$. Presumably since OP does not mention secondary constraints, there are none. Then  $C\approx 0$ is actually a [first class constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint). By the [Dirac conjecture](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Dirac+conjecture), the [HVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $$\delta =\{C,\cdot\}\tag{1}$$ is a gauge symmetry. The [gauge-fixing condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) $\chi\approx 0$ should break the gauge symmetry $$\delta\chi ~=~\{C,\chi\}~\neq~ 0.\tag{2}$$  It should be stressed that the physical system does not depend on the gauge-fixing condition $\chi\approx 0$, cf. OP's question. The $2n\!-\!2$ dimensional phase space with the 2 constraints $C\approx 0\approx\chi$ is the physical/reduced phase space.